# ScriptEngineManager and ScriptEngine can not be loaded in Karaf OSGi (Nashorn not found)

Tags: javascript, java, osgi, apache-karaf, scriptengine

I am trying to use `ScriptEngineManager` and `ScriptEngine` to execute some JavaScript code with Java. I use Java 8 I am executing this code under Karaf OSGi.

The example I used works fine in a sample Java Class, but packing it in a bundle gives me this error `ScriptEngineManager providers.next(): javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory: Provider jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory not found`

When I look to the headers of the bundle, I see that the bundle imports `javax.script,` the package of the called classes but it seems that (nashorn) the provider is not found.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to file *etc/config.properties* (located inside of Karaf installation), find configuration property *org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation* and add jdk.nashorn.* to it. Complete configuration will be like this:

```
org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot,org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.principal,sun.*,com.sun.*,javax.transaction,javax.transaction.*,javax.xml.crypto,javax.xml.crypto.*,org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype,org.apache.xerces.stax,org.apache.xerces.parsers,org.apache.xerces.jaxp,org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation,org.apache.xerces.dom,sun.*,jdk.nashorn.*
```

[Bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-4603) is reported to Karaf community.

**Edit**: If you use Pax Exam Container 4.x for Karaf in your tests then don't forget to add `org.ops4j.pax.exam.CoreOptions.bootDelegationPackage("jdk.nashorn.*")` to the configuration of your test container.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you have a bundle or the system to actually export those packages in question:

So either install the corresponding bundle, or you need to tweak on the exports of the system bundle, in that case edit the jre.properties and make sure the package in question is exported from the system bundle.